# Applink not working inside iframe in Safari browser

Tags: javascript, iframe, safari, applinks

I'm trying to open my mobile application using javascript inside iframe.
It works fine in most of devices ( Android web browsers, iPhone firefox, iPhone Edge )
but doesn't work in iPhone Safari browser.

These are the codes that I've tried.

```
function openApp(){
    document.location = "myapp://someUrl"; // opening my app
}

function openAppTry2(){
    location.href = "myapp://someUrl"; // opening my app
}
```

It works fine if it's not in iframe , but has no reponse when the function is called from inside iframe.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I took reference from these posts but still couldn't use app link inside iframe.

https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/19928

[How to make iOS universal links work inside an iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40731036/how-to-make-ios-universal-links-work-inside-an-iframe)

Instead, I found other way to solve this problem using applink outside iframe.

Using window.addEventListener allows scripts inside iframe to call function that locates outside iframe.

```
window.addEventListener("message", callback, false); // init outside iframe
...
function callback (event) {
    useData(event.data);
    document.location = "myapp://someUrl"; // opening my app
}
```

and then use window.parent.postMessage to send datas to outside of iframe and call functions

```
window.addEventListener("message", setMessage, false); // init inside iframe
...
window.parent.postMessage(datas); // send data to caller of iframe
```

Answer (score 1):

window.top.location.href will be work！